# When printing strings into html page, PHP prints them on wrong places

Tags: php, oop

I have master class that has functions to print each part of website. I have a function that prints master-container which is a div that contains everything. (html/body/#master-container/(all website elements)). Inside that function I have abstract protected function that is used on web page (child class) to generate content that goes inside #master-container. This is part of code in master class:

```
  ...
  # print content
  abstract protected function print_content();

  # print master-container
  public function print_master_container(){
    $output = '
      <div id="master-container">
        '.$this->print_content().'
      </div>
    ';
    echo $output;
  }
  ...
```

And this is code in child class:

```
class Starting_page extends Core {
        public function print_content(){
            $this->print_navbar();
            echo 'test';
        }
    }
...
```

**Now the problem is** that it prints everything (both string 'test' and content printed by function `$this->print_navbar()` outside of `<div id="master-contaiener></div>`. How do I fix this code to actually print everything inside of the div.
Screenshot bellow shows the result of the problem inside Page source. Red cursor shows where items (highlighed in yellow) should actually be printed.

[image: Problem screenshot]

If there is need to show more code, say so.

Comment: Does `print_content()` echo the output or return it?

Comment: it has echo. when I put return on it it works well. however when I put return into protected function print_navbar() it doesn't print anything. (from the  that function)

Comment: As @Tristan says, you need to return contents of `print_content()`

Comment: The nav bar stuff probably echos too, so in the `print_content()` just do an output buffer and return contents at the end:  `ob_start();$this->print_navbar(); echo 'stuff'; $data = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); return $data;`

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, indeed. However, then a new problem accrues. When I return $output variable which is an output string, it prints nothing from the function.

Comment: I changed both echo into return in my methods. And I copy-pasted your code into my print_content method. However, it prints nothing expect string 'stuff'. Why is that so? I am sorry If this comment is stupid, and if so is my approach, I just started with PHP recently. $data variable seems to be empty, I used var_dump and then I also used print_r on that variable and it printed nothing.

Comment: If you changed `$this->print_navbar()` to return, then in this method you need to `echo $this->print_navbar();` so: `ob_start(); echo $this->print_navbar(); echo 'stuff'; $data = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); return $data;`

Comment: Excellent! That works now. I am grateful. I suggest to make answer with this information in case someone gets same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As good people in comments say, the problem was that specific methods used `echo` instead of `return`. However when `return` was used, there would be no output at all. Then @Rasclatt came up with solution for that too which is;

```
class Starting_page extends Core {
    public function print_content(){
        # output buffering start
        ob_start();

        # print navbar
        $this->print_navbar();

        # declare output buffering content
        $output = ob_get_contents();

        # add more output data
        $output .= 'other content';

        # end output buffering and return it
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Good thing to notice is that `$this->print_navbar()` still uses `echo` to print output. In case `return` is used then prefix `echo` should be added when calling this method.